# How do I populate report fields from "Household Account" or "Organization Account" instead of "Person Account"?

Tags: nonprofit-starter-pack, report-builder

My organization recently upgraded to the Nonprofit Starter Pack 3 and is using the Household Account Model.

Reports now are not populating the "Person Account" fields because "Person Account" refers to the deprecated 1-1 account records. It should instead populate "Household Account" or "Organization Account".

How can I switch the report fields pick list to support the new Household Account model?

[image: report fields]

[image: black Person Account fields]

Comment: It looks like you have person accounts enabled.  I know the npsp doesn't officially support them, but there is some guidance here https://powerofus.force.com/articles/Resource/NPSP-NPSP-and-Person-Accounts   

That said, I think you should be able to change the fields in the  to use the account fields instead of the person account fields.  

What exactly are you trying to do that you are not able to do?

Comment: @gorav Thanks. Do you know where to change the fields to use the account fields instead? I can't seem to find it.

I'm trying to run a report that includes the opportunity's salutation, first name, and last name, but the only option in the report fields picklist is the Person Account (see screenshot in original post).

Comment: What is the report type?  If you click customize, you should see the report type listed at the top left.

Comment: @gorav Report Type: Donations

Comment: I think that would be a custom report type, though it's possible opps have been renamed as donations. Can you try creating a new report using the opportunities standard report type?  Also, what fields do you see under account:general?

Comment: @gorav Yeah, it looks like Opps is renamed as Donations (I don't see an Opp standard report type). For account fields, see screenshot. ![Valid XHTML](http://imgur.com/a/N446I).

Comment: Remove the person account fields from the report and add account name and primary contact name. That should do it. You prob need to do data work to create contacts for all the existing person accounts, and remove access to the person account record type.

Comment: @gorav >"You prob need to do data work to create contacts for all the existing person accounts, and remove access to the person account record type."

Is there any documentation you recommend to do this?

Comment: I don't know the data model for person accounts well enough to say exactly what needs to be done.  I believe there is a contact and account for each person account.  So you would need to update each contacts account to a household account.  You might be able to just edit the account record type, you may need to create new.  Not sure.  This Salesforce doc just says to remove access to record type going forward but doesn't day what to do w existing data. https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000222040